# Convert string to mysql date format before insert

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a form which is used to upload a .csv file to insert data in mysql table. The file has a date column in a format "dd/mm/yyy". However I want to insert this date string in mysql date format "yyyy-mm-dd". I have the following code so far.

```
//parse data from csv file line by line
        while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
         //insert member data into database
         $db->query("INSERT INTO txns (txn_date, description, amount, status) VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[3]."')");
            }
        }

        //close opened csv file
        fclose($csvFile);
```

Please help to convert the date string to mysql date (yyyy-mm-dd) format.

Comment: let's not make use of built in functionality like LOAD DATA INFILE and instead try to reinvent the wheel while giving the uploader a chance to carry out an sql injection attack.

Comment: @e4c5 Hmm can you get `LOAD DATA INFILE` to automatically do date conversions?

Comment: depending on the text, yes @RiggsFolly you can do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($line[0]));  
// convert date to yyyy-mm-dd
```

and use **$date** as the value of column **txn_date**

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
$var = '05/01/2017';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$result = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Output: 2017-01-05.

Answer (score 0):

```
// date in dd/mm/yyyy format
$date = "05/01/2017"; 

//Explode by / to get an array with day, month, year in separate indexes
$dateArray = explode("/", $date); 

//Concatenate year, month and day into any format you want. 
$newDate = $dateArray[2] . "-" . $dateArray[1] . "-" . $dateArray[0];
```

You can make a function for this